# R why n_distinct provides different results?

Tags: r, dplyr

I assumed the following two usages should provides the same results. apparently not. anyone can help to explain a bit?

```
fr = data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,1),B=c(T,F,T,F) )

> fr  %>% n_distinct(.$A)
[1] 4

> n_distinct(fr$A)
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fr  %>% n_distinct(.$A)` is equivalent to `n_distinct(fr, fr$A)` which will evaluate the entire data frame, not just the `A` column.

Try `fr  %>% n_distinct()` and then try `fr$A  %>% n_distinct()` to see the difference for yourself.

Comment: understand. but .$A should be equally saying fr$A right?

Comment: No, that only works when the first argument is `.data`, for subsequent arguments

Comment: the way the pipe works is that it passes in the left hand side as the first argument to the right hand side. Thus, your call `fr  %>% n_distinct(.$A)` is equivalent to `n_distinct(fr, fr$A)` which of course will give 4.

Comment: good point. but, from n_distinct documentation, it's still unclear to me that .data should be the second argument instead of the first one.  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/n_distinct

Comment: `n_distinct` is not a data frame centric function, so it has no `.data` argument. Its only argument is `...`, and you can pass to it multiple vectors.

Comment: i found i may not understand on ".data" argument. this is the key element for my mis-undertanding. could you help to explain a bit?

Comment: most dplyr functions work in such a way that the first argument is the data frame you want to operate one. Then, when you want to reference a column in that data frame, you can use `.$`, because the `.` serves as a placeholder for the first argument (see `help("%>%")`).

Comment: understand. basically, it means n_distinct can't provide placeholder for ```.``` , right?

Comment: it does provide a placeholder, but it's just another argument.

Answer (score 0):

We need to extract the 'A' column and then apply the `n_distinct`

```
fr %>%
   .$A %>%
    n_distinct
```

Comment: fr %>%
   select(A) %>%
    n_distinct   is this also right?

Comment: @HappyCoding  You can do this in many different. ways.  I used the `.$A` as you were extracting it.  The usual way to preseve the table is `summarise(n = n_distinct(A))`